# How to connect asterisk server (in LAN) to an external softphone?

Tags: asterisk, lan, pbx

My asterisk is running in a LAN having local IP 192.168.1.8,broadcast address 192.168.1.255 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0.The external ip shown is 117.200.236.236 and port 59282 (using [IPMANGO](http://www.ipmango.com/)). Its dynamic.

I want to connect my mobile to asterisk.For that I use CSipSimple(android) as softphone and 3g service (BSNL,India)

NOTE:If instead of running asterisk in LAN if I use a data card (direct access, no LAN) I am successfully able to register my softphone.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/sip_nat_oneway_or_no_audio_asterisk.html) but it does not help.

**sip.conf**

```
[1000abc]
type=peer
externip=117.200.236.236
localnet=192.168.1.8/255.255.255.0
nat=yes,true,y,t,1,on
qualify=no
allow=all
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0 
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
secret=mysecret
host=dynamic
context=incoming-call
```

**CSipSimple Basic Account**

```
Account name:myAccount
Username:1000abc
Server:117.200.236.236
Password:mysecret
```

I have not made any change in **rtp.conf**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, network access:

- Set your firewall / router to forward your external IP to `192.168.1.8` on Ports 5060 (SIP) and 10000-20000 (for RTP), both with UDP packets
- Use a packet capture like wireshark or `tcpdump` to ensure network connectivity.

Secondly, nat setting:

You've got `nat=yes,true,y,t,1,on`, where you really need just:

`nat=yes`

That's proper for asterisk 1.8. Asterisk 11 will require different options, see the `sip.conf` file as generated by `make samples` -- which I highly recommend if you're new to asterisk, the sample configurations contain the best documentation about the settings.

Lastly, in cSipSimple:

In `Settings -> Network` tick the box for `use 3G (and better)` in order to send data over 3G, otherwise it typically defaults to just `use Wifi`.

Comment: Thanks.Can you please elaborate how to set firewall to forward externalIP to 191.168.1.8 on ports 5060 and 10000-20000 for RTP?Morever does my CsipSimple require any other specififcation?Do I have to edit rtp.conf?

Comment: It worked.thanks.although my sip is unable to disconnect and I am getting the following **warning**.chan_sip.c:3670 retrans_pkt: Hanging up call sEX.p0LSspOV1mBfz17DFaAUYxJZIfvf - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
  == Spawn extension (incoming-call, 300, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/1000abc-00000002'

Comment: Typically a network issue. Check out the link it gives, it's written by Olle, and he's a top-notch VoIP guru.

Comment: @dougBTV which link you are talking abt. ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your network public ip it is also configure in your SoftPhone. Also make sure that your external ip matches your public ip in your network.

sip.conf

```
[1000abc]
type=peer
externip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX
```

You can use [this site](https://www.whatismyip.com/) to find your external IP.